# Append new element to eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have two tables posts and photos. Each post has 5 photos. I want to list in view each post with one photo (profile pic), first picture.

```
$published_post = Post::where('created_by',auth()->user()->id)
                        ->where('status','published')
                        ->get();

$photo = Photo::where('post',$published_post->id)->get();
```

These two gives me two different collection. How can I add the first photo of a particular post to its array so in view I can display using a foreach loop.

This is how I want in view:

```
@foreach($published_post as $item)
    {{ $item->title }}
    {{ $item->profile_photo }}
@endforeach
```

I tried put and push, but doesn't seem to be working. Not sure how exactly does we append a new key value pair to an object.

My two models:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->integer('post');
    $table->timestamps();
});

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
}


class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'photos';
    protected $fillable = ['image', 'post'];
}
```

Comment: show your Post and Photo Model

Comment: added, please check

Comment: Define a `hasMany` relationship between `Post` and `Photo`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships for details on how. Will need a bit of additional logic to only show one while iterating, but try that out first. Also, regarding your edit, those aren't the models; those are the migrations. Show the contents of `Post.php` and `Photo.php`.

Comment: @Thomas that is database schema, got to app folder you will get there Model and yes you should add post's  primary key as a foreign key in photos table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Post Model:**

```
<?php

    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


    class Post extends Model
    {
        /*This is used to specify the table which this model is associated with*/
        protected $table = 'posts';

        protected $fillable = [
          'title'
        ];
        public $timestamps = true;

        public function photos(){
            return $this->hasMany(Photos::class,'post');
            //post is the foreign key for posts table
        }
    }
```

**Photo Model:**

```
<?php

    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


    class Photo extends Model
    {
        /*This is used to specify the table which this model is associated with*/
        protected $table = 'photos';

        protected $fillable = [
          'image', 'post'
        ];
        public $timestamps = true;

    }
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($published_post as $item)
    {{ $item->title }}
    {{ $item->photos->first()->image }} // photos relation is invoked and fetched first image
@endforeach
```

Comment: Answer me a question.
As far as I know, the example above is missing, there is specification that: from the photos table you need to have the post_id column with the Post Id to which the photo or photos belong. without that, there is no way to relate things. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. post_id should be used as a foreign key in the photo table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 Models, one for Posts and one for Photos.

```
php artisan make:model Post
php artisan make:model Photo
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    //
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Then create a hasMany relationship on the Post model to link to the Photo model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Photo;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can lazy load the photos whenever you like

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    {{ $post->photo[0]->name}}
@endforeach
```

The syntax to go in your view will be slightly different, but this gives you a good idea on how the functionality should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you should change your Post model like this:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'post');
    }
}
```

And then, add the following to your Photo model:

```php
class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'photos';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post');
    }
}
```

With this, you've created the relation between your models, and now you can get your data this way:

```php
$published_post = Post::where('created_by',auth()->user()->id)
                      ->where('status','published')
                      ->with('photos')
                      ->get();
```

And in your view, you can get the first photo this way:

```php
@foreach($published_post as $item)
    {{ $item->title }}
    {{ $item->photos()->first()->name }}
@endforeach
```

For more info on relations, you might want to read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

I hope this helps!